# Transforming point from EPSG:3844 to EPSG:3857 with proj4js

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, proj4js

I'm having an issue transforming a point from [EPSG:3844](https://epsg.io/3844) to [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) using `Proj4JS`. The transformation it performs seems off compared to the result given by `PostGIS`, `pyproj`, `rgeo-proj4` or even [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3844&t_srs=3857&x=432142.9450000&y=474552.6700000).

`PostGIS` sample:

```sql
select st_astext(st_transform(st_geomfromtext('point(432142.945 474552.670)', 3844), 3857));
```

This is the code in question ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxgwejcn/)):

```js
proj4.defs([
  [
    'EPSG:3844',
    '+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=2.329,-147.042,-92.08,0.309,-0.325,-0.497,5.69 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs',
  ],
  [
    'EPSG:3857',
    '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs',
  ],
]);
const actual = proj4('EPSG:3844', 'EPSG:3857', [432142.945, 474552.67]);
const expected = [2685681.568887065, 5743146.959786006];
console.log('Actual:', actual);
console.log('Expected:', expected);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.8.0/proj4.js"></script>
```

I suspect it has something to do with the Helmert transformation parameters given in `+towgs84=2.329,-147.042,-92.08,0.309,-0.325,-0.497,5.69`? If so, what are the correct parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You are right regarding wrong `towgs84` parameters. If you take the ones from https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3844/html/:

```
TOWGS84[33.4,-146.6,-76.3,-0.359,-0.053,0.844,-0.17326243724756094]
```

you'll get much better result: `[2685681.014671648, 5743147.970431625]`. It's still not exactly what you expect, but at least you know where the discrepancy comes from.

Comment: Is there a central authority for this? I've also seen a different set of parameters in this [commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Web-Client/pull/155/commits/04e558f0b084ecf98b55bb86595362ad108e0ff3) that offers a result that's closer to the expected value. Although at this point I'm questioning everything - what's the correct value? It's just an assumption that the expected value I mentioned is right.

Comment: Official place for EPSG:3844 is https://epsg.org/crs_3844/Pulkovo-1942-58-Stereo70.html, but unfortunately WKT info there https://epsg.org/crs/wkt/id/3844 now gives data in WKT2 format, which does not have info about `towgs84` transform.